# Unity Android build error - required API level

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, sdk, game-development

I'm trying to test a game on my Galaxy Note 9. It works with Unity Remote but I can't get it to build to test it as an App. I'm getting this weird error "Required API level 26" when I try to build it.

I reinstalled Android Studio
Researched online
Checked Unity Android path
Messed with Player Settings to see if something was missed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9QkC.jpg

Unity should build the game.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Studio >SDK manager and update your SDK. It will go away.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait on the reply... There was no update so I decided to add in the other SDKs. After 45 mins of installing all the SDKs I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Yes everything says it's up to date in Android Studio. https://imgur.com/a/5oqQEGk

Comment: There's absolutely nothing online or on Unity's website explaining this... I'm just about ready to reinstall Windows this is so frustrating.

Comment: It happened to me. When i manually deleted the old versions of build tools, it got fixed. They are on Users⁩/name/Library⁩/⁨Android⁩/sdk/build-tools. I do not know the exact path for windows. If it does not fix your issue, try removing old versions from Users⁩/name/Library⁩/⁨Android⁩/sdk/platforms.

Windows path -> C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Restoring "Library" folder in project folder helped to resolve the issue.